# Pagerfanta symfony Pagination

Tags: symfony, pagerfanta

I have a mysql database blog with 21 posts in it.
I set $maxPerPage = '3'; So I get 7 pages, but from page 4 I get the following error:

OutOfRangeCurrentPageException: Page "4" does not exist. The currentPage must be inferior to "3"

Here's my code:

```
  public function indexAction($page)
```

{

```
$maxPerPage = '3';
$currentPage = $page;

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
->select(array('u')) // string 'u' is converted to array internally
->from('AppBundle:Blog', 'u');
$adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($queryBuilder);
$pagerfanta = new Pagerfanta($adapter);
if (!$page) $currentPage = '1';
try  {
    $pagerfanta->setCurrentPage($currentPage);
}
catch(NotValidCurrentPageException $e) {
  throw new NotFoundHttpException('Illegal page');
}
$pagerfanta->setMaxPerPage($maxPerPage); // 10 by default






//$textblog = $this->getDoctrine()
  //->getRepository('AppBundle:Blog')
  //->find($page);


return $this->render('textblog/blog.html.twig',array('pagerfanta' => $pagerfanta));
```

}

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me...

```
$pagerfanta->setMaxPerPage($maxPerPage);
```

This code should be before the 'if'